# Pinning Array of .NET objects

Tags: c#, .net, mono, garbage-collection, interop

I would like to pin an array of .NET objects (including the objects) in order to allow a native function to do some processing on the objects. As far as I understood, GCHandle.Alloc() does not allow me to do this, because such an array contains references (and the objects might also contain references) which are not blittable.

Is there any other option to achieve this? I would be okay with very hack-y suggestions or ones that require Mono.

Comment: What do you expect to be able to do to these objects even if you could get them pinned? References aren't necessarily pointers; you won't be able to access them from the native side.

Answer (score 10):

Arrays in .NET are represented in contiguous memory.  So that means that in memory, after element 0, element 1 will come *directly after* the previous element, and so on.

If you pin the array with [`GCHandle.Alloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f.aspx), then that means the *entire* list of elements is pinned in memory as well, and you can process that in unmanaged code.

However, as you've mentioned, it only makes sense if the type is a blittable type (technically, this is not true, it's if the type is able to be marshaled to unmanaged code, although there's a lot of overlap here between the blittable primary types and stuff that the P/Invoke/COM Interop layers handle automatically).

So if you have an array of value types, you can call `GCHandle.Alloc` and it will pin the array for you.  However, the P/Invoke layer *already* does this for you, so you shouldn't be concerned with this.

If your array is full of references, then marshalling it to unamanged code doesn't make sense anyways; even if you pin every reference, the unmanaged code wouldn't know what to do with that reference in memory, as the type system doesn't support the .NET type that the reference is pointing to in memory.

If the class in .NET is really a wrapper/.NET representation of a native structure, then you're better off creating an array of that structure in .NET, copying all the data into it, and then sending it to your native code.

Or, you could write your class in C++/cli to facilitate the access of the .NET members in native code.

Comment: @casperOne - I was referring to an array full of references. From my perspective, pinning the array and every object that is referred by the array does make sense. The C code just has to be aware that it is dealing with a C# array and C# objects and access its fields via pointer arithmetic that mimics the default memory layout of the CLR.

Comment: If you get an array full of references, pin the array and pin all the references in the array, you still have to deal with what I mentioned in my fifth paragraph: you don't know what the type system is in native code, so those pointers mean nothing to you.  If you *already* are using C++/CLI for mixed code (.NET and C++ code) then you should just expose a class/method that takes the .NET type to begin with, as you're gaining nothing by doing this.

Comment: So far I did not succeed pinning an array with references (same for an object with reference type members), is this possible? To your fifth paragraph: Once I have a solution for the pinning problem, this will be the next challenge - analysing the .NET memory layout and writing C functions that can convert types into something that is useful from C.

Comment: @user1622959 that's the whole gist of the answer, you shouldn't be doing this, you should be marshaling the data across the managed/unmanaged boundary.  The answer is "no, don't do that, use marshaling".  Why do you want to read the CLR types? What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve, I guarantee this isn't it.

Comment: Imagine I have a huge, really huge array of objects and I want to iterate over them and perform operations based on some of their member-values in native code. Now imagine that this is very performance critical and copying GBs of objects around in memory isn't an option. Then the only thing left is pinning and trying to write C code that can handle C# memory layout and types.

Comment: If that's the case, *you're already doing the wrong thing*. Ideally, you'd have a class that performs these operations in native code and minimizes the input that you need to shuttle across the managed/unmanaged boundary.  To that end, you should look at C++/CLI, and expose a .NET class through that which will access the native code.  This will give you exposure to .NET, but also access to the native structures.  Think larger, less granular entry points.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and `Marshal.WriteIntPtr`. This is the official way that framework provides to work with unmanaged memory. Not sure if it will be helpful though.

**Edit**

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/878147/301525

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @casperOne - my imagination tells me if he wants to accomplish what he asked in the question, the only way is if he marshals all his array into unmanaged block.

Comment: The P/Invoke or COM interop layers do this for you automatically.

Comment: @casperOne - it sounded like the op wanted to do it himself. It might be unnecessary, but what if his intention is to call some assembly code later to process the array, and he can't use P/Invoke.

Comment: More than likely he can't call assembly code first without first shuttling the array to native code that is exposed by C/C++.

Comment: @m0s - As soon as any kind of copying is involved, the solution would be unacceptable from a performance point of view. So it has to be via pinning or other means that prevent the GC from moving the objects around while the native code is executing.

Comment: @user1622959 my answer is not only not efficient but also not practical in 99% of cases, that's why I upvoted casper's answer first. However I added my answer as a direct answer to your questions, if for some reason you'd need to pin the objects and you couldn't take advantage of pinvoke then these are the methods to use.