# How can I pin an array of byte?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I want to pin an array of bytes which is 10 megabytes long so that managed and unmanaged code can work on it.

My scenario is that I have an unmanaged driver which reads some data from the device and writes it to the big array and the managed application just reads that data.

Something like this:

```
byte[] dataArray = new byte[10*1024*1024];
```

I want to pin dataArray so that GC does not move it.

What happens actually when I just run the application, I get a DataAbortApplication, and after reading on the internet I found out that I should pin the `dataArray` to avoid this error.

How/what should I do?

Comment: Check out the `fixed` statement http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293133/pinning-array-of-net-objects ?

Comment: @FabianBigler: you mean I can't share the big array between managed and unmanaged code?

Comment: This array can't move, it is too large so is allocated on the Large Object Heap.  Whatever your problem might be is surely related to something else.  Your "DataAbortApplication" is a meaningless diagnostic.

Answer (score 36):

There are 2 ways to do this. The first is to use the `fixed` statement:

```
unsafe void UsingFixed()
{
    var dataArray = new byte[10*1024*1024];
    fixed (byte* array = dataArray)
    {
        // array is pinned until the end of the 'fixed' block
    }
}
```

However, it sounds like you want the array pinned for a longer period of time. You can use [GCHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx)s to accomplish this:

```
void UsingGCHandles()
{
    var dataArray = new byte[10*1024*1024];
    var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(dataArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    // retrieve a raw pointer to pass to the native code:
    IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

    // later, possibly in some other method:
    handle.Free();
}
```

Comment: This will work if the managed and unmanaged code is in the same process.  To share cross process you would need to use a memory mapped file.

Comment: Looks like there have been some changes to the GCHandle API since 2014. Now, it looks like you have to do this: `var ptr = GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle)`. `ToIntPtr` appears to have been made static.

Comment: Use `handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()` instead of `handle.ToIntPtr()`

Comment: @hillin I took the liberty of applying your fix to this answer. `ToIntPtr` and `FromIntPtr` would be used if the managed environment needs to completely forget about both the array and the handle for a while, storing the `IntPtr` inside unmanaged memory as an opaque handle. And that would ideally be done with `GCHandleType.Normal` because pinning for long periods of time messes with the GC.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a class that can be used to pin a byte array until is disposed. However it sounds like a memory mapped file would be more appropriate in your scenario.

```
public class PinnedBuffer : IDisposable
{
    public GCHandle Handle { get; }
    public byte[] Data { get; private set; }

    public IntPtr Ptr
    {
        get
        {
            return Handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        }
    } 

    public PinnedBuffer(byte[] bytes)
    {
        Data = bytes;
        Handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            Handle.Free();
            Data = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this may require a finalizer that calls Handle.Free(). From the docs, "When the handle goes out of scope you must explicitly release it by calling the Free method."