# C# - convert any unsafe unmanaged type to managed type without any new memory allocation - keeping the same size in memory

Tags: memory-leaks, .net-core, marshalling, managed

**I want to convert ushort array to short array, without any allocating to a new memory in C# core.**

**Also convert any type, such as byte[] to short[] or vice versa - The conversion need to keep the same size in memory for both source and destination**

In C there was "union" syntax, which the type can be referred with several type-casting - I didn't find any equivalent for C# (that works only for non-primitive types).

One way is to code like this

```
ushort[] res = new ushort[1024 * 1024 * 1024];
short[] s = new short[1024 * 1024 * 1024];
Buffer.BlockCopy(s, 0, res, 0, s.Length * 2);
```

... but, I don't wont to allocate the 's' value - It's too much memory consuming, and may leads to memory leak.

Another alternative I use is using unsafe mode.

The code:

```
unsafe
{
    ushort[] res = new ushort[1024*1024*1024]; // large allocating
    fixed (ushort* ss = &res[0])
    {
        IntPtr ps = (IntPtr)ss;
        short[] s0 = (short[])Marshal.PtrToStructure(ps, typeof(short[]));
    }
}
```

run into exception.

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>
> ...
>
> at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor)
>
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStructure(IntPtr ptr, Type structureType)

**How can I eventually convert that big array of 1G bytes, without the need of allocating new memory?**

**Can I convert array type from unmanaged type to managed type?**

**I prefer using the unsafe mode, if ever possible.**

---

After deep search, I found a solution, which I would participate (and editing this post), but it has a problem as describe as following:

**That's code working very well, if the arrays are of the same size - There is a new question - How can I solve it for non same array base type size (i.e. short[] vs byte[]) ?**

The only thing I cannot convert from short[] to byte[].

(Thanks, to some blog on the internet: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/06ac44b0-30d8-44a1-86a4-1716dc431c62/how-to-convert-an-intptr-to-an-object-in-c?forum=clr)

That works on C# core as well on C# .NET

First thing, create a class:

```
public static class MyConverter
{
    public static unsafe T GetInstance<T>(IntPtr pointer)
    {
        try
        {
            var fakeInstance = default(T);
            TypedReference typedReference = __makeref(fakeInstance);
            *(IntPtr*)(&typedReference) = pointer;
            T instance = (T) __refvalue(typedReference,T);
            return instance;
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

and can use it in code like this:

```
      ushort[] x = new ushort[1024];
      GCHandle handle1 = GCHandle.Alloc(x);
      IntPtr px = (IntPtr)handle1;
      x[0] = 1;
      x[1] = 2;
      x[2] = 3;
      short[] s = MyConverter.GetInstance<short[]>(px);
```

That solution convert ushort[] to short[] without any waste of memory.

Thanks.

Comment: Please dont edit an answer into the question. Use the Answer section

Comment: It was not an answer (I deleted my answer, but it is not quite perfect. The answer lacks of convert that I cannot really do (byte[] <-> short[], because short and byte are not the same size).

Comment: alright.. I reverted it

Comment: Thank you. I almost revert back my deleted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily convert like this: `(ushort[])(object)myShortArray`. The CLR allows this.

It's only allowed for primitive array element types that are the same size.

In other cases you can use `Span` to treat the memory as a different type.

```
Span<int> asInts = MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, int>(asBytes);
```

Comment: I didn't understand. For the following code, I cannot run SetArr. As I said - I must convert to different type. No Span<something>. just byte[]...  public void SetArr(byte[] b)
{
}

public void Run()
{
      var arr = new byte[10];
       Span<byte> bytes = arr;
       SetArr(bytes); }

Comment: @Eitan you cannot convert the array type directly. There is no way. Base your code entirely on span. That way you can convert in-place *like* an array.

Comment: As my example of MyConverter I can, but this works only for short[] to ushort[] i.e (short and ushort are the same size. When I convert to byte[] it has the half size, which have to be the size*2).  I need to use the managed type, because I am using some 3rd party libs, that the parameters is an array (of ushort, or short, or byte - I need to support all of the types). It's seems silly thing that I cannot just making reference to the same memory (like the old 'union' in C++).

Comment: @Eitan OK, if the 3rd party library cannot accept a different type you are out of luck. An array is an object header plus length plus the data. You can't make an array that points to different memory. This is not an arbitrary rule but there is no way to implement such a thing. Span is for that.

Comment: The unsafe tricks you found would not change the `Length` property. If the library does not make use of that property you might get away with forcefully changing the static type of the object reference. You could do that with the `Unsafe` class in .NET Core. This might very well break the runtime (particularly the GC). So this is a very risky strategy.

Comment: If instead of "short[] s = MyConverter.GetInstance<short[]>(px);" I do: "byte[] b = MyConverter.GetInstance<byte[]>(px);" sizeof(b) is same size of the original array, but need to be double in size. b and s point to the same memory. I hope GC will not get confused about that, and free only one of them (they using the same pointer). The actual size is always in bytes. There must be a way to handle this. It's look too silly if not (why should I allocate another 1G bytes, or any extra byte, just to move data between functions using parameters). I persume in C++ code, that was much simple.

Comment: Also, when I evalute the type of byte[] is UShort16, and can have values > 256 (so, actually it has the original values). Maybe unsafe is not the right solution. What I am looking is 'union' equivalent in C#.

Comment: Before Span, C# did not recognize the possibility of taking a "view" over arbitrary memory. This is a strength of C that has been sorely missing indeed. Modern APIs often use Span, not arrays. Unfortunately, we are now stuck with the legacy way of doing it.

Comment: Note, that .NET arrays bundle type, length and content. C pointers only have content (not even length). That makes them more flexible.

Comment: .NET has unions (struct with LayoutKind.Explicit). But they would be per-element of an array. No way to overlay two arrays.

Comment: Span<byte> is fine, but if arraySpan = MemoryMarshal.Cast<short, byte>(array); convert short array to byte array - How can I convert the Span<byte> to byte[] array? (Without creating new block of memory).

Comment: How can I get the IntPtr of Span?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. You might need to pin the underlying memory.

Comment: So how can I pin the underlying memory?

Comment: I suggest you type ".net pin array" into a search engine. It's better explained there compared to what I can put into a comment. You will not encounter any problems with pinning and pointers. They are as flexible as you would expect.

Comment: I saw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254759/how-can-i-pin-an-array-of-byte, but this is may be appropoiate for byte[]. I cannot do something like : GCHandle.Alloc(myspan,  GCHandleType.Pinned)

Comment: Span is not pinnable because it can work with memory that is not pinnable (unmanaged for example). You need to keep track of the underlying array together with the span. Pin the underlying array. Then you can use both pointer and span.