# .Net System.Span<T>: does it pin the underlying object and protect it from compaction?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Perhaps the answer is "depends on which ctor was used"?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0

`Span<T>(Void*, Int32)`: I'm sure it doesn't (can't) pin... How about `Span<T>(T[])` and its cousin `Span<T>(T[], Int32, Int32)`?

By "pinning" I mean [How can I pin an array of byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254759/how-can-i-pin-an-array-of-byte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `Span<T>` doesn't pin anything.  If it did, what would be the point of [`Span<T>.GetPinnableReference()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.getpinnablereference?view=net-6.0) ?

Note that the documentation for `GetPinnableReference()` says

> Applications should not directly call `GetPinnableReference`. Instead, callers should use their language's normal pinning syntax, such as C#'s `fixed` statement.

From that we can again infer than an object is not pinned by `Span<T>` alone, but is pinned if `fixed` is used.

Comment: Hmm that's an interesting point, and as I read more about this topic, it became clearer that I had confused a managed pointer (whose value .NET GC has a full control over) with an unsafe pointer