# Working with strings between C# and C++

Tags: c#, c, interop, low-level

I have a problem that I think is very common among low-level developers whose start working with high-level languages. I made some research but didn't find a suitable solution to my problem.

I have a client-server application and I want to re-create all the client, from "scratch" using C# but as I want to keep the server as it is, the "new" updated client have to follow the actual protocols of sending and receiving data packets.

If the packets just contains unmanaged types (`byte`, `int`, etc) it should be ok, but my problem comes up when I have to work with strings between the managed client in C# and the unmanaged server in C/C++.

I already have found some solutions for this problem, but I really don't know which is the best or if there is a better solution that i didn't notice.

The first approach is use the `fixed` keyword to create structs that represents each packet of the application and doing this the C# allows me to easily and with very low cost (I guess) do my pointer casts (from `byte*` to `packet_structure*` and vice-versa) without worry about all the marshaling and other expensive methods. I think this approach is particular bad because forces me to use a `sbyte` data type on the buffers where should be a string in the packet and then make a cast to bring these bytes to the managed world to be properly processed.

The other approach I have made was to declare the struct of each packet as managed but marked with `MarshalAs` attributes to make use of the `Marshal`'s methods for converting the data. This approach I think is more expensive, considering that the application is a game and the client, which I'm doing, is a real-time application. I think that make extensive use of marshaling on each packet can be very much expensive for the application.

Is there any simple and beautiful solution which I could follow something like C style or any other solution that my inexperience is denying me? In C a very simple pointer cast should be enough to free me the problems.

I'm in love with C# but I'm veeeery afraid I couldn't do this with this platform :(

Anyone could please shed me some light? :/

Thanks very much for your time, any kind of help will be VERY appreciated.

Comment: *"This approach I think is more expensive, ..."* I suggest that you take some time to profile it! Do you really consider making your code more complicated just because of a *gut feeling* that the easy and most readable (and, thus, least error-prone) solution *might* be too slow?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/878073/87698

Comment: @Heinzi thanks for your answer. I will read the topic you send right now.

Comment: @Heinzi I just read the topic and... Well, I will follow your guide to profile the code and find myself the better way. The aim of this topic is just to sum up knowledge about the topic. As i'm not yet an expert with C# I thought that people here could point another way I wasnt seeing. Thanks very much for your fast answer =]

Comment: You can make it work.  No, it is giant mistake to have the lowest level dictate the way this works.  We are living in the Internet age, this is an entirely solved problem.  Uplift the low end, there is no reason to avoid using XML or Protobuf in C++ today.

Comment: Hi Hans. The problem of using XML or Protobuf as you said is that it's not an option to change the server app, so I'm stuck with the actual packets protocol without using serialization (which could solve me the problem). But yeah, maybe I'm overthinking about the processing, idk ;x Thanks very much for the response.